# Android app does not show in appstore to download to Samsung Galaxy Tab® 2 7.0 (Verizon)

Tags: android

I have a android app in google play store,When I try to install it into Samsung Galaxy Tab® 2 7.0 (Verizon) via google play, application does not show on device(Try to download as user). When I login through web the device shows in not supported list,Application shows to other galaxy tabs without any issues and can download from appstore,Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shipxpress.mportal.demo"
    android:versionCode="75"
    android:versionName="5.6.3"  >

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.shipxpress.mportal.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <receiver android:name="com.shipxpress.mportal.sms.MessageReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without at least your manifest.

Comment: I added manifest file to the question

Answer (score 0):

On your manifest you should add this

```
<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

And on your res folder add this folders:

```
layout-large
layout-small
layout-xlarge
```

You can see the documentation  [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Hope it helps.

Comment: <supports-screens/> already there, but I have not included the layouts in res folder, because I am using kendo UI to this project